# Java Swing inactive button for window close

Tags: java, api, swing, jframe

I am trying to create a gui using swing. I have a main frame and I want it to only show the x button at the top right corner. I would also like to make this button impossible to press if certain conditions are met. I did some search on google and on java's website but I couldn't find any functions related to these two tasks. Any small pieces of code or links to tutorials or apis are welcome.

I want the button to be there. I don't want the window to close (which I can do with the setDefaultCloseOperation) and also I'm trying to find a way to be able to make the button look greyed out and not allow it to execute the animation of getting pressed in when I click on it. I want it to be there but grey and totally non responsive.

Comment: What do you mean by "impossible to press"? Do you want to force the mouse away if it gets to close to it? How would you want to prevent the user from pressing it?

Comment: @Joachim Sauer I think he wants it disabled

Comment: i want it to just be there but showing in greyscale and if you click it it would be like clicking nothing. It just wouldn't respond. It would be inactive i guess.

Comment: @Eternal_Light: Also read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942056/remove-x-button-in-swing-jdialog

Comment: see my edit about real chooses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe    `myFrame.setResizable(false);` and all of Events for this Button you can hande [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334618/java-swing-hide-frame-after-button-pressed)

EDIT:

window's decorations coming from Native OS, and then you have this four options as follows

- full decorated (JFrame) minimize/maximize/close Button
- only close Button JDialog and JFrame#setResiziable(false)
- undecorated, then there missed minimize/maximize/close Button(a) and toolBar (that came from Native OS) too
- undecorated [Top-level Container](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) with [JPanel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) (with [GradientPaint](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GradientPaint.html) [simulated real](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Gradient-Paint.htm) ToolBar) contains [JButton](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) with Char X (could be enabled once time or another time disabled as you want)

Comment: If we use some themes then this will hide both maximize and minimize button but for default skin it disables maximize button (do not hide it) and minimize button is still there.

Comment: This is a really nice idea. I actually make my own toolbar and thus I'm able to edit it to my heart's desire :)

Comment: don't forget to set proper Border for example for JPanel (fatherPanel which nested another JComponents ) http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html , for plastic output to the screen (search for CoumpoundBorder)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a JDialog it just have got the X button

[image: JDialog]

And with `dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);`
  you can disable the close button.

With `dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);`
you can enable the close button

Answer (score 0):

You can specify what you want to happen when close button is pressed on your Frame. If you want it to do nothing, then:

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: Oh yea that is nice. Is there a simple way for me to also make it grey and not show the animation of being pressed inside when I click on it?

Comment: I don't think it's possible or at least not straightforward. You can remove all title bar stuff using setUndecorated() but that probably is no good to you. Maybe you also need to look into your use case, WHY do you need a window that is not closable? What method should the user use if they ever wish to close it? It doesn't seem like good UI design...

Comment: An example of a more standard approach to UI design for what you want is: when certain conditions are met, if the user presses close button show a message (dialog box or something like that) informing them that until those conditions are met you can't close the window. (and possibly give them an option to close it anyway if they want to)

Comment: I am mostly experimenting with it. I want to use it in situations like the following: The jframe is showing a progress bar and as long as the progress bar is not full I want the x button to turn grey and unusable and stay this way until the bar fills up. Sending out a message and requiring of the user to press another button to get rid of it isn't so nice when you can just disable the button. The user will understand the same things the message would tell them.

Comment: You can also use a JWindow instead in this case, it doesn't have those buttons by default...

Comment: But in the use case you mentioned, a better UI design in my opinion would be: while the progress bar is "in progress", if the close button is clicked then display a message to the user saying something to this effect: "Operation blah blah is in progress, do you want to cancel progress and exist?". If you don't give user an option of closing it in a civilised manner, they can always use CTRL+ALT+DELETE and Kill task option!

Comment: I was just planning to disable the x and give him a cancel button below the progress bar :P This way he could stop the progress but not close the whole program or get rid of the window.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't search very far. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29. Passing `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE` to this method will forbid the frame to be closed via the default close button.

Comment: Yes, this is basically what I want it to do, but I was trying to make it totally nonresponsive. ie. when I click it I don't want it to execute the animation of being pressed in.

Comment: Ah, OK. I don't think it's possible using a JFrame.

Comment: Could I achieve this using something different? Even if I have to use something else instead of swing?

Comment: You could make the frame undecorated and provide your own decorations, or you could ask the look and feel to provide the decorations for you and hack it to make it display a grey button for your JFrame subclass, if some "closable" property is false. Look at the JFrame javadoc (setUndecorated, setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated) for explanations. But I fear it won't be such an easy task.