# Mantaining focus in application even when it have subwindows

Tags: java, swing, focus, focuslistener

I need to implement a routine that ensure that the application will never lose the focus for others applications (however when it is minimized I shouldn't force it come back). So I decided to implement WindowFocusListener in the main window:

```
public class DialogoPrincipal extends JFrame implements WindowFocusListener {

    public DialogoPrincipal() {
        initComponents();
        this.addWindowFocusListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
        //Do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void windowLostFocus(WindowEvent e) {
        this.toFront();
    }

    /*hidden code*/
}
```

It works great when the main window don't show any subwindows. But when some subwindows are opened, I can't force the focus for the application.
Is there a way I can force the focus in the application, even when the application have subwindows, or I need implement WindowFocusListener in all of my dialogs?
If I need to implement this interface, what can I do for JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(...) don't lose the focus to?

Comment: for better helps sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), just about `JFrame`, two `JDialogs` with `JButton` invoking `JOptionPane`, [could be based on](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7335171/714968)

Comment: You can call `setFocusableWindowState(false)` on each of the subwindows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it implementing an abstract class that is inherited by all subwindows:

```
public abstract class DialogoFocado extends JDialog implements WindowFocusListener {

    public DialogoFocado(Frame owner) {
        super(owner);
        this.addWindowFocusListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void windowLostFocus(WindowEvent e) {
        this.toFront();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

- not possible to maintain [Focus, FocusRecycle, FocusSubSystem, ZOrder betweens JFrames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html) correctly, dirty hack have to add `JFrames` to `two_dimmensional array`, which is supply `FocusWhatever` and with `proper ordering`
- `FocusWhatever` is simple `asynchronous`, because is based on properties came from `Native OS`, have to delay `FocusWhatever` inside `invokeLater`,
- logic for [Dialog Focus (AncestorListener) by @camickr (have to hold ancesors in Array)](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/) could be usefull for proper container hierarchy `JFrame` & `JDialog`
- use [JDialog with Parent and proper ModalityType](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28java.awt.Dialog,%20boolean%29), then `focus` could be returned back to the `Parent`